# Postgres - Delete operation not completing

Tags: postgresql

Looking for some help to run below `delete` in another way as below is long running.

```
delete from dbo.customer 
where ac_no not in (select ac_no from dbo.account)
```

Comment: Maybe it's waiting for a lock?

Comment: A delete trigger may also be the problem. For big update statements you may want to temporarily disable for-row triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps PostgreSQL can optimize a `NOT EXISTS` clause better:

```
DELETE FROM dbo.customer
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.account
                  WHERE customer.ac_no = account.ac_no);
```

But without seeing `EXPLAIN` output it is hard to say.